# Invalid Filename when adding image to Office via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I'm getting an Invalid Filename exception when trying to add an image to the Word Document in C#.

The image does save but to the location using the same filename but it fails to embed into the document.

```
foreach (XmlElement childnodes in node.GetElementsByTagName("events"))
            {
                string name = childnodes.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText;
                string location = childnodes.GetElementsByTagName("location")[0].InnerText;
                string time = childnodes.GetElementsByTagName("time")[0].InnerText;

                XmlAttributeCollection xmlAttributeCollection = childnodes.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0].Attributes;
                if (xmlAttributeCollection != null)
                {
                    var newName = FilenameFromTitle(name);
                    var image = xmlAttributeCollection["src"].InnerText;
                    var imagename = "images/" + newName + ".jpg";
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(image,newName);
                    }
                    document.Content.Text += "===================================================================================";
                    document.Content.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagename,false,true);
                    document.Content.Text += "EventName" + name;
                    document.Content.Text += "Location" + location;
                    document.Content.Text += "Time" + time;
                }
            }
```

This is an example of one of the generated names.

> "images/corb-lund-ca-altcountry--sarah-jane-scouten-ca-am.jpg"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to insert the file as an end-user, in Word, or does that also give you an error (possibly more informative)? Side note: Even once the error message goes away I don't think you're going to get the result you're looking for. If you keep reassigning to document.Content each assignment is going to replace what was there, before. You need a Range object and it should be collapsed prior to each assignment...

Comment: adding the image works in word.the range thing as it is works with text atleast